# How to approach development of new Qt 5.7+ High-DPI Per Monitor DPI Aware application?

Tags: c++, qt, highdpi

I have read the official [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) and many articles and questions on StackOverflow about high DPI support in Qt. All of them focus on porting old applications and making them work with as least changes as possible.

But if I were to start a brand new application, with the intention to support per-monitor DPI aware app, what is the best approach?

If I understand correctly, `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` is the very opposite of what I want. I should actually disable HighDpiScaling and calculate all the dimensions manually on runtime?

Many of the suggestions say not to use sizes at all, to use floating layouts. But in many cases at least minimum width and/or minimum height is desired to be present. As Qt Designer only allows me to put values in absolute pixels, what is the right approach? Where should I place the code to recalculate dimensions if monitor resolution changes?

Or should I just go with the automatic scaling?

## My solution from previous Qt app (not well tested)

In one of my older apps where I tried to add HighDPI support, I used this approach - list all children of DOM and resize them one by one given some ratio. Ratio = 1 would produce dimensions equal to the ones I specified in Qt Designer.

```
    void resizeWidgets(MyApp & qw, qreal mratio)
    {

        // ratio to calculate correct sizing
        qreal mratio_bak = mratio;

        if(MyApp::m_ratio != 0)
            mratio /= MyApp::m_ratio;

        // this all was done so that if its called 2 times with ratio = 2, total is not 4 but still just 2 (ratio is absolute)
        MyApp::m_ratio = mratio_bak;

        QLayout * ql = qw.layout();

        if (ql == NULL)
            return;

        QWidget * pw = ql->parentWidget();

        if (pw == NULL)
            return;

        QList<QLayout *> layouts;

        foreach(QWidget *w, pw->findChildren<QWidget*>())
        {
            QRect g = w->geometry();

            w->setMinimumSize(w->minimumWidth() * mratio, w->minimumHeight() * mratio);
            w->setMaximumSize(w->maximumWidth() * mratio, w->maximumHeight() * mratio);

            w->resize(w->width() * mratio, w->height() * mratio);
            w->move(QPoint(g.x() * mratio, g.y() * mratio));
            
        }

        foreach(QLayout *l, pw->findChildren<QLayout*>())
        {
            if(l != NULL && !(l->objectName().isEmpty()))
                layouts.append(l);
        }
        
        foreach(QLayout *l, layouts) {
            QMargins m = l->contentsMargins();

            m.setBottom(m.bottom() * mratio);
            m.setTop(m.top() * mratio);
            m.setLeft(m.left() * mratio);
            m.setRight(m.right() * mratio);

            l->setContentsMargins(m);

            l->setSpacing(l->spacing() * mratio);

            if (l->inherits("QGridLayout")) {
                QGridLayout* gl = ((QGridLayout*)l);

                gl->setHorizontalSpacing(gl->horizontalSpacing() * mratio);
                gl->setVerticalSpacing(gl->verticalSpacing() * mratio);
            }

        }
        
        QMargins m = qw.contentsMargins();

        m.setBottom(m.bottom() * mratio);
        m.setTop(m.top() * mratio);
        m.setLeft(m.left() * mratio);
        m.setRight(m.right() * mratio);

        // resize accordingly main window
        qw.resize(qw.width() * mratio, qw.height() * mratio);
        qw.setContentsMargins(m);
        qw.adjustSize();
    }
```

which is called from main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyApp w;

    // gets DPI
    qreal dpi = a.primaryScreen()->logicalDotsPerInch();

    MyApp::resizeWidgets(w, dpi / MyApp::refDpi);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I don't consider this a good solution. Given that I am starting fresh and I can fully customise my code to the latest Qt standards, what approach should I use to get HighDPI apps?

Comment: On Win32, we found success with simply querying the OS (GetDeviceCaps) for the monitor's dpi setting, dividing by 96.0, and setting the env variable `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` to match.  There be tradeoffs.  On Mac, we didn't have to do anything.  YMMV.

Comment: @selbie, how setting QT_SCALE_FACTOR address per-monitor scaling?

Comment: Maybe this QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS [list] specifies scale factors for each screen. This will not change the size of point sized fonts. This environment variable is mainly useful for debugging, or to work around monitors with wrong EDID information(Extended Display Identification Data).  BUT unsure, anyone care to try to set it from within the app?

Comment: @AlexanderVX - fonts scale fine with QT_SCALE_FACTOR if you use `font.pixelSize` to set.  It's not just a debugging tool, it's the only way to ship a QML app without having to pollute your QML code with some sort of scaler function for each literal number.  QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS can work too.  But the environment variables are only read once when Qt initializes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If I were to start a brand new application, with the intention to
>   support per-monitor DPI awareness, what is the best approach?

We don't rely on Qt for automatic scaling in per-monitor DPI aware mode. At least Qt 5.7-based app with `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` set does not do that and 'high DPI scaling' is more of accurate drawing regardless of pixel density.

And to invoke per-monitor DPI aware mode you need to modify `Qt.conf` file at the same directory where you project executable file is:

```
[Platforms]
# 1 - for System DPI Aware
# 2 - for Per Monitor DPI Aware
WindowsArguments = dpiawareness=2

# May need to define this section as well
#[Paths]
#Prefix=.
```

> If I understand correctly, Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling is the very
>   opposite of what I want. I should actually disable HighDpiScaling and
>   calculate all the dimensions manually on runtime?

No, it is not an opposite but a different thing. There is a couple of Qt bugs closed as no-bugs: [QTBUG-55449](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55449) and [QTBUG-55510](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55510) that show the intent behind the feature. BTW, there is [QTBUG-55510](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55510) a programmatic workaround for setting Qt DPI awareness without fixing `qt.conf` is provided (use at own discretion because it uses 'private' Qt implementation classes that change the interface without any notice with newer Qt version).

And you expressed the correct approach to do the scaling in per-monitor DPI aware mode. Unfortunately except that there is no much alternative at the time. There programmatic ways to assist the event handling for the window scaling when it is moved from one monitor to another, though. The method like `resizeWidget` (one, not many) at the head of this question should be called using something like (Windows):

```
// we assume MainWindow is the widget dragged from one monitor to another
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
{
   MSG* pMsg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);

   switch (pMsg->message)
   {
      case WM_DPICHANGED:
         // parameters TBD but mind that 'last' DPI is in
         // LOWORD(pMsg->wParam) and you need to detect current
         resizeWidget(monitorRatio());
         break;
```

This is quite difficult and troublesome way to go and I resorted to enable the app to switch between System and Per Monitor DPI Aware modes by letting the user to choose the mode and restart the app process (either fixing `qt.conf` or doing workaround from [QTBUG-55510](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55510) at the app start). Our hope is that Qt company realizes there is a need for per-monitor DPI aware mode with auto scaling for widgets. Why would we need it (?) is another question. In my case I have per-monitor rendering within own app widget canvas which supposed to be scaled.

At first, reading the comment to this question from @selbie I realized maybe there is a way to try to set QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS while the app starts:

> QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS [list] specifies scale factors for each
>   screen. This will not change the size of point sized fonts. This
>   environment variable is mainly useful for debugging, or to work around
>   monitors with wrong EDID information(Extended Display Identification
>   Data).

I then read [Qt blog](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/) on how to apply multiple screen factors and attempted to do the below for 4K and 1080p monitors where 4K is listed first (main).

```
qputenv("QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS", "2;1");
```

That does helps a bit: almost correct rendering *but* introduces defects with window size while moving the window from one monitor to another pretty much like [QTBUG-55449](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55449) does. I guess I will go with `WM_DPICHANGED` + `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` approach if the customer considers current app behavior as a bug (we make the same base for all monitors DPI via System DPI Aware). Still there is no ready to use solution from Qt yet.

Comment: thank you for the answer. the lack of support for easy highdpi solution as in Android programming drives me crazy. is there something i should add to my resizeWidgets function? do you know of any opensource demo app with Qt highdpi features? thx

Comment: @TomášNavara Unaware of opensource solution for that yet. I tried and going that way is a mine field of doing way too many routine scaling. You already show the understanding of what needs to be done programmatically but in Windows you can take advantage of WM_DPICHANGED, MAYBE setting QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS [list] will work BUT for already connected monitors when you start the app. I've added a couple of statements for that.

Comment: so just to clarify - what advantage does it have to specify dpiawareness = 2 when I do all the work myself from within the code upon receiving dpichange event? and what about linux?

Comment: You said "intention to support per-monitor DPI aware app". That is how the Per-Monitor DPI Aware mode invoked. Or see the workaround  QTBUG-55510 with parameter 2. Or read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280512(v=vs.85).aspx The meaning of that mode is that Windows passes the event WM_DPICHANGED to the app process. And MacOS does similar.