# How to purge QMainWindow's geometry tag in Qt Designer UI files

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer, uic

Qt Designer adds a geometry tag that contains the widget's default size in absolute units (pixels).

This is really annoying because if you edit a `ui` file on a 4k monitor all of your `ui`s will (by default) display with massive white space on a lower DPI system.

If I manually delete this tag, my windows have the expected size on first-show, but manually editing every `ui` file each time I open them in Qt Designer feels wrong.

I'm using Qt 5.9.

What's the paradigmatic way to prevent Qt Designer from adding this XML tag?

In `example.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Example</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Example">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>970</width>
    <height>1371</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
```

Comment: To "normalize" your UI on 4K monitor you can do:

    Simply put this before QApplication app object initialized:

    `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);`

    I could have put that in form of the answer but the question is more about Designer?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823918/how-to-approach-development-of-new-qt-5-7-high-dpi-per-monitor-dpi-aware-applic/39824445#39824445

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yeah, that's different. The problem is that Qt Designer sets size hints that are specific to the DPI/resolution of the developer's machine.

Comment: Why not to try smth like `mainwindow.setGeometry(screen.width() / 4, screen.height() / 4, screen.width() / 2, screen.height() / 2);` // so you will ensure it is proportional to the screen. And you can detect what screen it is on.

Comment: @AlexanderVX On one hand that is not a bad idea, on the other hand the layout is "perfect' when I manually delete the line from the `ui` file.

Comment: I guess nested layouts may help so that you avoid fixed things.

Comment: You simply need to use layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to remove the geometry tags in Qt Designer like this:

1. Open a new Main Window form
2. Select **geometry** in the Property Editor
3. Click the red arrow on the right

This will automatically resize the form - but manually resizing it won't reinstate the geometry tag. However, if the form has a menu-bar, it will also add a geometry tag for that. So select *menubar* in the Object Inspector and then repeat steps 2 and 3 above. After doing that, I get this output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar"/>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

And after adding other widgets/menus/layouts and resizing the form, the geometry tags never reappear. This was all tested using Qt Designer 5.10.1 on Linux.

Comment: Yeah. This looks like the most reliable way. Seems that all children need to be "reset" to effectively loose those tags.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using qmake for your project:

One possible solution would be to create an intermediate "compiler" that first transforms the ui file to remove the geometry tag and that passes it to uic - this way you can at least automate the process of removing the geometry tags.

The code for the PRO-file would add a new compiler like this:

```
uiungeom_c.name = fix ui of ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
uiungeom_c.input = RAW_FORMS
uiungeom_c.variable_out = FORMS
uiungeom_c.commands = /path/to/<some_command> ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
uiungeom_c.output = ./.uifix/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.ui
uiungeom_c.CONFIG += target_predeps
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += uiungeom_c
```

And change the `FORMS` in your pro file to `RAW_FORMS`, i.e.

```
RAW_FORMS += mainwindow.ui #...
```

This will run the `<some_command>` on all your ui-files and generate a copy of them without the geometry in your build folder in a subfolder. Those generated ui files are automatically passed to the `FORMS` variable and thus are now passed on to `uic` to create the header.

---

The tricky part here is the `<some_command>` - You would have to create some kind of script (bash, batch, python, XSLT-Transformation, ... - whatever you prefer) that takes the original xml file as input and removes the tag. XSLT-Transformations are propably the most elegant and reliable way, but also the most complicated - you can learn more about them at [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp), but I would propably just use python, as it propably leads the the smallest and easiest to understand script.

(If you would like to see a basic sample in python that could do the job, I can fiddle one out later the day - just ask for it as a comment)

Comment: Welp. I don't use qmake, but yes, parsing XML is  one strategy to remove the tag...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to prevent Designer from writing this, I often find it simpler to just revert by code what has been done.

In this case I would suggest adding a call to `setSize(sizeHint())` at the end of the constructor of your main window.